# How do I troubleshoot the boot process ending up in the fastboot menu after LineageOS 17.1 upgrade?

Tags: boot, lineageos

I have an OnePlus6 (enchilada) which was working fine with LineageOS 16. I've just upgraded it to 17.1 following [the official upgrade doc](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/enchilada/upgrade) and using OpenGapps.

Now, after the whole procedure, I am stuck in the fastboot menu, where I can either shutdown or boot to recovery.

How do I **troubleshoot**? Is there some way to gather boot logs?
Or maybe there's a way to turn the boot process into a more verbose one?

(I tried booting into recovery, only then I get `adb` access, but no `/proc/last_kmsg` there as people suggest, and the `/proc/kmsg` contains only the recent boot logs)

Comment: I checked the `/boot` partition - it doesn't seem to be altered in the boot process. I judge it by trying to boot several times and checking the md5sum afterwards - `adb pull /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/boot_a /tmp` has the same checksum as the one I extract from the OTA mega-zip with payload_dumper

Comment: probably gapps installed to */system* instead of */system_root/system* upgrade [TWRP 3.3.1-18 Q Unofficial by mauronofrio](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3860815) and *'adb pull /tmp/recovery.log'* after installing gapps